# String with additional characters at the end passes Date strptime

Tags: ruby

I need to check if string is a proper date.

```
date = Date.strptime(date_string, '%Y/%m/%d') rescue nil
```

Unfortunately, `Date.strptime` finds the date at the beginning and ignores other characters, so

```
date_string = '2017/02/13dsasdsadasdasd'
```

will pass the check. Is there any way to make check more strict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a general solution, but here is one that works for this specific case:

```
date = Date.new(*date_string.split("/").map{|s| Integer(s)}) rescue nil
```